# How to stop iframe loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, upload

Hi I'm uploading a file through an iframe.

HTML:

```
<from action="upload.php" target="iframe">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" src="javascript:false;"></iframe>
```

Now I would like to abort the upload while uploading. So I would like to stop the iframe loading.

**What I've tried**

`$("iframe").attr("src", "javascript:false;");`

`$("iframe").remove();`

```
if (typeof(window.frames[0].stop) === "function")
    window.frames[0].stop();
else
    window.frames[0].document.execCommand("Stop");
```

All functions don't throw an error but after a while the file I've canceled was displayed in the upload folder. So that's the weird thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `window.stop` cancels any _further_ resource loading but not the original request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you can destory the `iframe` element, any HTTP requests it has made cannot be cancelled. This is by design of HTTP.

The closest analogy is that it's like trying to stop a bullet you've fired by destroying the gun.

Answer (score -1):

Try flash uploaders. They have many advantages against standard uploading input, like multiple file upload, stopping upload queue, file size limit etc. Try a demo here: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/. Of course they have a bit complicated implementation.

Comment: Flash uploads don't have any advantages this was just a question for the ie solution all major browsers except ie support HTML5 multiple file and ajax uploads even with image preview, given size in JavaScript aso. btw flash is outdated for me we've got HTML5 now! Don't look back!