# "Can only update a mounted or mounting component " warning in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Theoretically, I should be able to asynchronously fetch some data and update my component inside of `componentDidMount`. Here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/api/sessions')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ sessions: data.body })
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sessions</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.sessions && this.state.sessions.map(session => {
            return <li key={`session-${session._id}`}>{session._id}</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

The component renders, and re-renders when the data is received. But I'm getting a warning:

```
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the App component.
```

Shouldn't I be able to assume that `componentDidMount` implies the component actually mounted? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that the component has been unmounted before the request completes?

Comment: If that's the case you will have to cancel you request in the componentWillUnmount. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110982/how-to-cancel-all-requests-in-componentwillunmount

Comment: @bitshift I added log statements to `componentWillUnmount` and in the callback to the request, and it appears the component is unmounting before the request completes. What's also odd is that after the two log statements, the warning appears, and then the callback log for a second time! I'm not sure why or how, but it appears the component mounts, unmounts, and then mounts again.

Comment: @djfdev Maybe the parent component is doing something during that time that would cause the component to mount/unmount/mount?

Comment: @bitshift Unfortunately, this is the only component (i.e. what's being rendered by `ReactDOM.render()`.

Comment: How is the code bundled and executed?

Comment: @bitshift Thanks for mentioning that, I wouldn't have even thought to look in my webpack config. I'm using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, which I did not realize was automagically inserting a script tag for my bundle into the template (I had included the script tag in the template myself already). So basically, it was loading and rendering the React app twice. Removing the script tag solved the problem .... dohh.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent it You can maintain a state say isMounted and update it on componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount. And whenever you are asynchronously trying to set state, first check whether the component is still mounted or not.

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.setState({
      isMounted: true
  })
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.setState({
      isMounted: false
  })
}

componentDidMount () {
 fetch('/api/sessions')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (this.state.isMounted) {
       this.setState({ sessions: data.body })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This seems like an anti pattern – i.e. it implies that `componentDidMount` does not actually do what is says.

Comment: It is not `componentDidMount ` fault. You are doing an asynchronous call which is being completed after even your `componentDidMount` got finished and also your component unmounted. That is why this error is coming.